What Star Wars audio book had a pilot providing a password for a restricted region of space?
Years ago I listened to an audio book of one of the many Star Wars-verse stories, where a female pilot approaches a restricted region in her spaceship, repeating over the communicator a — from my viewpoint — beautiful password.
The password was longer than a single word. The female (human, to be precise) pilot was anxiously repeating the password as she approached, fearing someone will shoot before receiving the password.
Does anyone remember the story title and/or the password?

Do you have a rough guess when you might have listened to it?

I listened to it some three years ago. The book itself might be much older.

The plot sounds familiar, but cannot remember where I read it. But I never listened to audio books, so it must be one of the books before 2000, maybe in the original trilogy books by Timothy Zahn? Does Mara Jade ring a bell?

@wink2000 As Charlie Chan would say: No bell, sorry.

It's possible that this is the novel Death Troopers (2009) by Joe Schreiber.
The only thing that doesn't fit is that the female is not the pilot, but the Chief Medical Officer Zahara Cody. Her password is 'Blackwing'.

Blackwing was the password to a secret biolab project, not a region of space.

No, it's not Death Troopers / Blackwing. The password was longer. The female (human, to be precise) was the pilot. She was anxiously repeating the password as she approached, fearing someone will shoot before receiving the password.
